# Is there any solution, where I can write single onClick method for all rows in table in Android?

Tags: android

my requirement is that, I have a table with multiple rows where by selecting single row should display its contents on screen. I figured out that by writing onClick() for every row its achievable, but its not feasible to write multiple onClick()'s for multiple rows. So is there any way to achieve this without writing multiple onClick()'s.

This is my XML for table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
       android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
         >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_margin="0.2dip"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="0.2dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/code" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_margin="0.2dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/name" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_margin="0.2dip"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="showData" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code1"
                android:layout_margin="0.2dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/code1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code2"
                android:layout_margin="0.2dip"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/name1" />
        </TableRow>
```

I have written onClick for second row.

This is onClick() in activity class:

```
public void showData(View view){
        text = new EditText(this);

        //text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.displayData);
        TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code1);
        TextView tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code2);
        TextView tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayData);
        tx3 = new TextView(this);
        String str = tx1.getText().toString();
        String str1 = tx2.getText().toString();
        tx3.setText("CODE : "+str+" "+"NAME :"+str1);
        //text.setText("CODE : "+str+" "+"NAME :"+str1);
        //text.setText("NAME :"+str1);
        setContentView(tx3);
    }
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to write `android:onClick="showData"` for each table row in the XML? Why is that "not feasible"?

Comment: I can write android:onClick="showData" for each table row...but how to manage it in activity class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `view.findViewById(R.id.code1)`, etc. (instead of `findViewById` without the `view.`) to find the text view specific to each row. That way all rows can use the same `android:id` values and a single `onClick` method for all rows. (This is similar to how a `ListView` works.)

```
public void showData(View view){
    TextView tx1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code1);
    TextView tx2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code2);
    . . .
}
```

If you want to cut down on the sheer size of the xml, you can put the attributes into a style.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the efficient code but you can use this,
get your table id

```
tableLayoutGrid = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourtableid);
        int count=tableLayoutGrid.getChildCount();
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            TableRow row=(TableRow) tableLayoutGrid.getChildAt(i);
            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                       TextView tx1 = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
                        TextView tx2 = (TextView) row.getChildAt(1);
                        TextView tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayData);
                        tx3 = new TextView(this);
                        String str = tx1.getText().toString();
                        String str1 = tx2.getText().toString();
                        tx3.setText("CODE : "+str+" "+"NAME :"+str1);

                }
            });
        }
```

I hope this will help you..